# mysql where statement working in phpmyadmin but not on site

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t_modules` WHERE nPageM='61'") or die(mysql_error());
```

In phpmyadmin it returns (as expected) 2 rows but on page it returns 0.
If i use

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t_modules` WHERE nPageM<>'61'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t_modules`") or die(mysql_error());
```

it runs on the page correctly it's just the WHERE and = combination that doesn't work
I also checked that the type for nPageM is int(11)

**UPDATE**

I can run comparisons on other columns in the table but not on nPageM

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t_modules` WHERE id_md='5'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Is working. But i still don't have a clue about why it's not working on the nPageM column

Comment: You said the type for nPageM is int(11). Have you tried not putting quotes around the 61?

Comment: @evilone: lol! nice. zenify, don't be a leech. Go back and accept answers on some of your old questions.

Comment: Do you get an error message or just a zero result?

Comment: @ Raffael, no, it's just a zero result.

Comment: @Scott, yes, i tried without quotes too

Comment: @zenify: What happens if you run `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_modules WHERE nPageM='61'"` in PHP? Does it work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you ensured that you have included a connection to the databse in your php script before running this code?

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('sqluser', 'sqlpassword', 'sqlserver');
$db = mysql_select_db('dbame', $con);

//now, make sure it's connecting
if (!$con) {
die('mysql connection error' . mysql_error());
}
if (!$db) {
die('mysql Database error' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Nick, my connection checks out fine.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply but it turns out there was a problem with my connection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead try putting brackets around it:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `t_modules` WHERE (nPageM<>'61') ") or die(mysql_error());
```